# Relation between tree-width and clique number

Tags: graph-theory, treewidth

Are there any nice graph classes for which the tree-width $tw(G)$ is upper-bounded by a function of the clique number $\omega(G)$, i.e. $tw(G)\leq f(\omega(G))$?

For example, it is a classic fact that for any chordal graph $G$, we have $tw(G)=\omega(G)-1$. So, classes related to chordal graphs could be good candidates.

Comment: tw$(G) = \omega(G) - 1$ for chordal graphs.

Comment: since treewidth is closed under taking subgraphs, if a graph $G$ has $K_n$ as subgraph then the treewidth of G must be at least the treewidth of $K_n$, which is $n-1$.

Comment: @Matheus I think the question is the other way around. He is asking for an upper bound and your example gives a lower bound.

Comment: $tw(G) \leq  \omega(G)$ for split graphs, i.e., graphs whose vertex set can be partitioned into an independent set and a clique. (Take one bag containing the clique, then for every vertex v in the independent set make a new bag containing the clique with v, and attach the bag in the tree decomposition to the bag containing just the clique.) For all hereditary graphs containing all complete bipartite graphs or all grids, there is no such bound, ruling out a lot of natural classes.

Comment: @Yixin Cao: edited.

Comment: @Bart Jansen: split graphs are chordal.

Comment: @FlorentFoucaud, you should consider turning your edit into an answer.

Comment: @Vinicius dos Santos: OK, done.

Comment: There has been a lot of study recently on $\chi$-bounded graph classes, which are defined by taking your question and replacing treewidth with chromatic number.  Since treewidth gives you an upper bound for $\chi$, every $\chi$-bounded class of graphs satisfies your constraint.

See http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1145 for an example of recent research.

Comment: @Andrew D. King: I think that gives me the wrong way: bipartite graphs are obviously $\chi$-bounded but I can't upper-bound the tree-width by the clique number (see e.g. grids, as pointed out by Bart)

Comment: Sorry of course you're right; I'm thinking backwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On [this page](http://www.eprisner.de/Journey/Opti.html) a theorem is mentioned that provides such classes:

**Theorem** (Scheffler [1]) If $G$ is the intersection graph of connected subgraphs of another graph $H$, then $tw(G)\leq tw(H)\omega(G)-1$.

This generalizes the bound for chordal graphs (for which $H$ is a tree) and also applies to circular-arc graphs (then $H$ is a cycle). I do not know if other "standard" classes are captured by this theorem.

[1] P. Scheffler, What graphs have bounded tree-width? Rostocker Math. Kolloq. 41 (1990) 31-38.

Comment: "inaccessable"? you mean paper is not online?

Comment: Actually at first I thought this is a conference talk but obviously this has some page numbers. There is a website for the journal (http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/math/pub/romako/), I've asked whether it is possible to obtain a copy.

Comment: I think it's also not hard to prove it yourself. Possibly it's faster than receiving a copy of paper :)

Comment: @Saeed Possibly, but I'm especially hoping to find some discussion about the topic in that paper!

Answer (score 6):

**Theorem (6.4 in [1]):** If $G$ has no pan and no even hole as an induced subgraph, then $tw(G)\leq 3\omega(G)/2-2$.

**Theorem (5.4 in [2]):** If $G$ is odd-signable, has no clique cutset and has no cap nor any 4-cycle as an induced subgraph, then $tw(G)\leq 6\omega(G)-1$. (In particular, this holds if $G$ has no clique cutset and has no cap and no even hole as an induced subgraph.)

[1] K. Cameron, S. Chaplick, C. T. Hoang. On the structure of (pan, even hole)-free graphs, 2015. https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03062

[2] K. Cameron, M. V. G. da Silva, S. Huang, K. Vušković. Structure and algorithms for (cap, even hole)-free graphs, 2016. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08066

Answer (score 2):

This recent paper studies the question in more depth:

Clément Dallard, Martin Milanič, Kenny Štorgel. Treewidth versus clique number in graph classes with a forbidden structure. https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.06067